How to calculate column percent from multiple groups in a T-SQL table?
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I have a table that looks similar to the one shown in the picture below. I would like to calculate the column percent for each group in the table.
The values in the "Group" column are not fixed and can vary.
enter image description here
Is there a T-SQL command or query that can help me achieve this?
I have tried a few approaches, but I'm not getting the desired results.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Please read the following guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and edit your question accordingly. I'm sure this is fairly simple to resolve but there are too many unknowns at the moment. Fix your question and update the tags to include the RDBMS, give sample data as a DDL script so we don't have to type it all in to test any possible solutions.

Isn't this just a simple: SELECT *, 100.0 * ModeValue / SUM(ModeValue) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupCode) from yourtable

I've made a a lot of assumptions here as your question was not clear enough. I've assumed.

Only two values will ever be present for each group
The Modes will only ever be 'OK' and 'NO'
Both Modes will always exist
The ModeValue will never be NULL or 0
The is running on SQL Server


DECLARE @GM TABLE(GroupCode varchar(10), GroupMode varchar(10), ModeValue decimal (20,10))
INSERT INTO @GM VALUES 
    ('AG', 'OK', 72),
    ('AG', 'NO', 5076),
    ('AR', 'OK', 433),
    ('AR', 'NO', 1197),
    ('BU', 'OK', 72),
    ('BU', 'NO', 2603)

SELECT 
    o.GroupCode,  
    o.ModeValue as OKValue, 
    n.ModeValue as NOValue, 
    (o.ModeValue/(o.ModeValue + n.ModeValue)) * 100 as PercentValue
    FROM @gm o
        JOIN @gm n on o.GroupCode = n.GroupCode 
    WHERE o.GroupMode = 'OK'
        and n.GroupMode = 'NO'

Note the ModeValue column is decimal, if it really an INT then you may need to cast it in the PecentValue calculation.
The code simply joins the table back to itself so each group is represented as a single row and then calculates the percentage as per you question.
This gives the following results



GroupCode
OKValue
NOValue
PercentValue




AG
72.0000000000
5076.0000000000
1.39860139860140


AR
433.0000000000
1197.0000000000
26.56441717791411


BU
72.0000000000
2603.0000000000
2.69158878504673



A note on the PecentValue column: Typically you would not multiply by 100, instead you would format the output in the front end app/report etc. but that's down to you..
